# c# FileInfo class being used in SSIS Script Task Directory.GetFiles SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly being ignored

Tags: c#, ssis, fileinfo

I am using the following Script Task to enumerate over a file directory, then pull a list of files and load them into a Recordset Destination.  I don't want to drill down past the directory I specified @"E:\Data Warehouse\Imports\TIMECLOCK" in my search.  There's a subsequent folder inside TIMECLOCK called PROCESSED, where it's supposed to move the files into later.  So I'm only trying to grab the ones in the folder above, TIMECLOCK.  So I used the SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly in the Directory.GetFiles function, but it's drilling down past that to the PROCESSED folder, as evidenced by my Data Viewer (see Data View screenshot after the code). At first I was using a variable to pass in the search directory, but it was doing the same thing, so I explicitly declared the search directory, and it's still not working. I don't know what I'm doing wrong!

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
#endregion


[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent{

public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    string sourceDirectory = @"E:\Data Warehouse\Imports\TIMECLOCK";
    string searchFileName = "Business Units GL Segments_Sent Weekly*";
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, searchFileName, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(sourceDirectory);

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        String FileFullPath = Path.GetFullPath(file);
        fileInfo = new FileInfo(FileFullPath);
        OrderedFilesBuffer.AddRow();
        OrderedFilesBuffer.FileName = fileInfo.Name;
        OrderedFilesBuffer.FileDate = fileInfo.LastWriteTime;
        OrderedFilesBuffer.FilePath = fileInfo.FullName;
    }
  }
}
```

[image: DataViewer]

Comment: What happens if you add a trailing slash to the directory to search?  e.g. `@"E:\Data Warehouse\Imports\TIMECLOCK\"`

Comment: You can create a DirectoryInfo() to get the FileInfo's directly using the EnumerateFiles (or GetFiles) methods. That way you don't need to create the FileInfo later. Bit of a performance advantage and can potentially solve your other problem of the TopDirectoriesOnly being ignored.

Comment: btw EnumerateFiles can have some performance advantages, GetFiles() has to go off and get all the file entries first from the File System, EnumerateFiles will return each time it has had a chance to get a record from the File System so you don't have to wait around.

Comment: @GlennWatson I was just about to write the exact same :-) Also: I think the initialization of fileInfo can be removed then (seems wrong anyways).

Comment: I agree I wouldn't expect that behaviour. Looks like this is used by SSIS, which I'm not familiar with... Does that cache the assembly? Maybe it's using an old version and you need to restart something to get it to pick up your change? (You could try hard-coding the date to a fixed value to see whether your changes are being used by SSIS, or whether it's using a cached version.)

Comment: I cannot  reproduce the problem, the code you've provided isn't [MCVE].

Comment: @BrendanGreen No difference with the trailing slash, I think I probably tried that at some point, lol!

Answer (score 0):

I am marking as answered because I am still completely not sure why this was happening, and I ultimately decided what I was trying to reproduce with writing the values to (2) file objects, then merging and getting a unique list of files between them to process, was really just a simple File Move task.  I was writing this for a client who originally designed it in Pentaho Data Integration that way and was reproducing it exactly in SSIS, when it was not really necessary.  I think since I was running both of these extractions simultaneously in the same Control Flow, it was using the same file path for both because of a cache issue of some sort and ignoring the TopDirectoryOnly.  At any rate, I trashed it and re-did the whole thing.